# page is not loading until binding finishing

Tags: xamarin.forms

```
    protected override   void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () =>
            {
     WaitingIndicator.IsRunning = true;
            var dataModel = new ClassListViewModel();
            ListViewClass.ItemsSource = dataModel.Classes;
            ListViewClass.IsPullToRefreshEnabled = true;
            ListViewClass.RefreshCommand = dataModel.RefreshCommand;
            ListViewClass.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#BDBAB6");
            ListViewClass.RowHeight = 200;
            ListViewClass.SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None;
            ListViewClass.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(Function);
            ListViewPagningBehavior ListViewBehaviour = new ListViewPagningBehavior();
            ListViewBehaviour.Converter = new ItemVisibilityEventArgstemConverter();
            ListViewBehaviour.Command = dataModel.LoadMoreCommand;
            ListViewClass.Behaviors.Add(ListViewBehaviour);
            //BindingContext = dataModel;
            ListViewClass.SetBinding(ListView.IsRefreshingProperty, "IsBusy");
            ListViewClass.BindingContext = dataModel;
            stack.Children.Remove(WaitingIndicator);
            });
```

i am flipping to the above page from another page 
my problem is that the page is not showing until the bindingcontext is finishing
but i want to show the waiting indicator to the user while waiting binding

Comment: Probably because you're doing everything on the main thread because of `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`

Comment: nope, the same result without Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread

Comment: What is happening in the constructor of your VM? `ClassListViewModel();` ?

Comment: fetching data from web service

Comment: my problem is that the navigation is delaying untill the second page fetches data from web service, if i remove the view model ClassListViewModel everything is going like a charm

Comment: i think this is similar to my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41423169/xamarin-forms-delay-in-navigation

Comment: @Immortal you found a solution?

Comment: @apineda Yea,it was a method in my view model that have to be async